# Por que minha requisição esta bloqueando eventos?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Implementei uma requisição http json que funciona bem, porem ela impede que o usuário efetue o click  podendo acessar a informação apenas quando ela estiver baixada.

Exemplo: Tenho uma UITableView com 3 Items, se eu clicar em um deles e nessa view estiver uma requisição ele não entrara na tela enquanto ela não estiver pronta.

**Exemplo da classe de requisição:**

```
class Requisicao {

    let urlDefault = "http://puc.vc/painel/webservice/"

    func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSData{
        let urlFull = urlDefault + urlToRequest
        return NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlFull)!)!
    }

    func parseJSON(inputData: NSData) -> NSDictionary{
        var error: NSError?
        var boardsDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(inputData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as! NSDictionary

        return boardsDictionary
    }
}
```

**Exemplo da Chamada:**

```
class ProcedAcadViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let request = Requisicao()
        let data = request.getJSON("procedimentosacademicos/")
        let json = request.parseJSON(data)
        println(json)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

}
```

Como posso resolver este problema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gabriel, não ficou muito claro pra mim qual é exatamente o problema. Pelo que entendi você quer fazer a requisição e assim que ela terminar fazer um transição de tela.
Existem várias abstrações para trabalhar com concorrência no iOS, sendo as mais comuns NSOperation e Grand Central Dispatch. 
Usando GDC, um fluxo bem recorrente é o seguinte:

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
    // realiza alguma operação em background (ex: requisição ao web service)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // atualiza a tela após completar a operação
    }
}
```

*dispatch_async* recebe dois parâmetros, uma fila e um bloco de código a ser executado nessa fila. Você pode criar suas próprias filas ou usar as criadas pelo sistema. 
No exemplo eu disparei um bloco de código para ser executado em background (sem bloquear a interface). Assim que essa operação termina eu faço alguma atualização na tela, a qual deve ser sempre feita na thread main (*dispatch_get_main_queue()*)

Comment: Da uma olhada no comentario da resposta certa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065536/downloading-and-parsing-json-in-swift

Comment: Você perguntou por que a requisição bloqueia eventos. Isso ocorre pois  você realiza a operação de download e parsing do json na main thread, que é responsável pelo tratamento de eventos e renderização da UI. É nessa thread que são chamados os métodos do ciclo de vida de UIViewController, como viewDidLoad. Para evitar esse travamento é necessário realizar essas operações fora da main thread.

Comment: Este dispatch_async deve ser executado na func viewDidLoad?

Comment: Pode ser. Na verdade tem várias formas de fazer. O importante é não fazer  esse tipo de operação na thread main. Senão pode travar a app e gerar um experiência ruim pro usuário. Além disso, se a app depende da requisição pra continuar a navegação,  sempre é bom mostrar que ela está processando algo, por exemplo usando o MBProgressHUD.

Answer (score 1):

Use alguma biblioteca de rede assincrona, tipo [AlamoFire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire).

```
class ProcedAcadViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.makeRequest();
    }

    func makeRequest() {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://puc.vc/painel/webservice/procedimentosacademicos/")
                 .responseJSON { response in
                      debugPrint(response)
                      // neste ponto vc tem um JSON e 
                      // podera atualizar o modelo e a table view
                 }
    }

}
```

Comment: +1,De fato, a principio decidi criar as funções que realizem requisições para aprendizado, porém como tenho pouco tempo e muita coisa para fazer ir para uma library que facilite isso tudo é bem melhor, estava utilizando AFNetworking mas irei migrar para Alamofire por ser criado em swift.